# NHibernate cascade convention for SaveOrUpdate and Merge only

Tags: .net, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I would like to configure a convention for NHiberate to allow cascade for SaveOrUpdate and Merge but not the Delete.
I can't find how to do this, since the Cascade.SaveOrUpdate() or Cascade.Merge() is returning void. And calling one method cancel the precedent.

Here are my trials:

1) the cascade will be for SaveUpdate :

```
 public class CascadeAllConvention : IHasOneConvention, IHasManyConvention, IReferenceConvention
    {
        public void Apply(IOneToOneInstance instance)
        {
            instance.Cascade.Merge();
            instance.Cascade.SaveUpdate();
        }

        public void Apply(IOneToManyCollectionInstance instance)
        {
            instance.Cascade.Merge();
            instance.Cascade.SaveUpdate();

        }

        public void Apply(IManyToOneInstance instance)
        {
            instance.Cascade.Merge();
            instance.Cascade.SaveUpdate();
        }
    }
```

2) the cascade will be for Merge:

```
 public class CascadeAllConvention : IHasOneConvention, IHasManyConvention, IReferenceConvention
    {
        public void Apply(IOneToOneInstance instance)
        {
            instance.Cascade.SaveUpdate();
            instance.Cascade.Merge();
        }

        public void Apply(IOneToManyCollectionInstance instance)
        {
            instance.Cascade.SaveUpdate();
            instance.Cascade.Merge();

        }

        public void Apply(IManyToOneInstance instance)
        {
            instance.Cascade.SaveUpdate();
            instance.Cascade.Merge();
        }
    }
```

3) the cascade will be deactivated:

```
 public class CascadeAllConvention : IHasOneConvention, IHasManyConvention, IReferenceConvention
    {
        public void Apply(IOneToOneInstance instance)
        {
            instance.Cascade.All();
            instance.Cascade.Not.Delete();
        }

        public void Apply(IOneToManyCollectionInstance instance)
        {
            instance.Cascade.All();
            instance.Cascade.Not.Delete();

        }

        public void Apply(IManyToOneInstance instance)
        {
            instance.Cascade.All();
            instance.Cascade.Not.Delete();
        }
    }
```